# ogr can't read shapefiles or json files even though geojson and esri shapefile are included in driver list

Tags: shapefile, gdal, geojson, ogr

I am running gdal/ogr on mac os 10.12.4. I recently reinstalled gdal and now am having an issue when I try to read shapefiles or geojson files - I get the error: `Unable to open datasource '/path/to/shp' with the following drivers`. And in the driver list I can see ESRI Shapefile as well as GeoJSON. I tested reading a kml and it did not have issue with that. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

I also just checked my installations and it appears I have 3 installs of gdal - I know I have v1.11 and v2.1, not sure what the 3rd one but maybe this is causing issues?

Comment: Does adding "-- debug on" to your ogrinfo command show more details?

Comment: I just checked and it says FAILURE: no data source provided. I am provided the full path of the file so not sure why that error.

Comment: Write the whole command. Is it like "ogrinfo my_shapefile.shp --debug on"?